# Recalculate average based on subset of poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, poisson-distribution, average, means

Assuming a series of independent events, probability of the event occurring on a given day is a poisson distribution with `λ=0.8`. This includes probability of event occuring `0, 1, 2, 3...` times.

Considering only the days where the `number of events is > 0` (using `λ=0.8`, probability of this occurring is):

$$\sum\limits_{y=1}^\infty \frac{\lambda^ye^{-\lambda}}{y!}=0.55067$$

I'm trying to work out what the average number of events would be ONLY considering the days where the number of events > 0 (ie 1, 2, 3...).

Comment: That probability $\mathbb P(Y>0) = 1-e^{-0.8}$

Comment: Note that $\mathbb E[Y] = \mathbb E[Y \mid Y=0]\,\mathbb P(Y=0) + \mathbb E[Y \mid Y>0]\,\mathbb P(Y>0)$